# ModelChoiceField: displaying a list with attritbutes of the selected objects

Tags: python, django

In a ModelForm I want to have the user select a user from a list of all user's last_names. After reading the [docs on ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) I thought I would use the following:

(in a ModelForm in forms.py):

```
myfield = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), to_field_name="last_name")
```

However, the effect is my form has the user select a choice from a list of usernames, and not of last names. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the docs you link to state, `to_field_name` changes the underlying value, not the display value. To change that you need to subclass the field and modify `label_from_instance`, again as shown in that doc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have obviously misunderstood this.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name):

> **to_field_name**
>
> This optional argument is used to specify the field to use as the `value` of the choices in the field’s widget.

When you use `last_name` as `to_field_name` you will see it in the `value` attribute of `option` tag and not as the display:

```
<option value="obj1.last_name">Object1</option>
```

The documentation also mentions what you need to do in case you want to change the display of those options:

> The `__str__` (`__unicode__` on Python 2) method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`.